# Keep a sub specific to the intended sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The follownig Excel sub runs every minute for several hours. It works fine unless I switch to a different workbook. At that point it bombs on the third line down.
How do I keep it focused on the sheet it is intended for?

```
Sub RunEvery60seconds()
          Range("A13").End(xlDown).Select
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
          ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
          Call Fetch
          Call OnTimeMacro
End Sub
```

There is probabbly some simple syntax that I have overlooked. I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: Qualify your sheet/range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub RunEvery60seconds()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("A13").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
                                                     Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
    Call Fetch         '<<< qualify all sheet references here
    Call OnTimeMacro   '<<< ...and here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I think I see how to qualify the references now.

Comment: No problem.  Also worth noting that wherever possible you should try to avoid using Select/Activate when working with sheets/ranges: relying on a particular sheet being active or a range selected makes you code difficult to debug as your project gets larger and you add more methods.